# Opening form's context menu

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I wanted to add a dropdown with a few options(shortcuts) next to the minimize button on my forms. To that end I followed the following example on Code Project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55180/Extending-the-Non-Client-Area-in-Aero.
This worked perfectly for what I wanted (I considered hiding the Border style but then I wouldnt be able to Dock the form on the edges of the screen) but for some reason disabled the ability to call the context menu on the title bar.

I noticed in the example that the WM_NCHITTEST event's override was not using the HTSYSMENU result and only returned HTCAPTION for the entire area of the title bar. I then changed the code to return the correct value if the mouse was on the left side of the title bar and with this I managed to call the context menu by left clicking on that corner.

```
Dim p As New Point(LoWord(CInt(lparam)), HiWord(CInt(lparam)))
Dim cap As Rectangle = RectangleToScreen(New Rectangle(0, dwmMargins.cxLeftWidth, Width, dwmMargins.cyTopHeight - dwmMargins.cxLeftWidth))
    If cap.Contains(p) Then
        Dim mp As Point = MousePosition
        mp = PointToClient(mp)
        If mp.X < 30 Then
            Return New IntPtr(HTSYSMENU)
        Else
            Return New IntPtr(HTCAPTION)
        End If
    End If
```

I can't however find how to activate the call to the context menu when right clicking anywhere on the title bar.
I tried overriding the message WM_NCRBUTTONUP on WndProc and send a message to show the Context Menu but nothing seems to happen.

```
 Dim WM_CONTEXTMENU As Integer = &H7B
 If m.Msg = WM_NCRBUTTONUP Then
        Dim mp As Point = MousePosition
        mp = PointToClient(mp)
        Dwm.SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_CONTEXTMENU, Me.Handle, Dwm.MAKEWPARAM(mp.Y, mp.X))


<DllImport("user32.dll")>
Public Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

I believe that I'm trying to reinvent the wheel and that I shouldn't need to be handling the WM_NCRBUTTONUP message to call the context menu since it should be handled automatically but I haven't found any information about it online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option, you can handle `WM_NCRBUTTONUP` and send a `WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU`:

```
case WM_NCRBUTTONUP:
{
    SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x313/*WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU*/, (IntPtr)0, m.LParam);
    break;
}
```

And this signature of `SendMessage` which I used:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Thanks. I already had that code. The problem was that I was using the wrong message value. I was using 0x7B instead of your 0x313

Comment: `WM_CONTEXTMENU` and `WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU` are two different messages. Also in your code you are getting mouse position again, while `WM_NCRBUTTONUP` has mouse position in its lparam.